# How can I manage more than 2 package groups with pipenv?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm looking for suggestions on how to use `pipenv` to manage multiple package groups.

In addition to the base and `dev` groups, I have `test`, `jupyter` and `dash`.

Comment: strange, that this highly actual question has so low upwotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since October 2022 this is now possible using the `--categories` argument:

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile.html#package-category-groups

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible. There are only 2 ways to install packages: production (no option) and non-production (option `--dev`). These [two groups are hard-coded](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/8203d3811af1828d93dd091eca008e9cf747ee68/pipenv/project.py#L739) in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to see this in official `pipenv` [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2303). My suggestion would go to have this directory structure.

```
├── project
└── requirements
    ├── dash
    │   ├── PipFile
    │   └── PipFile.lock
    ├── dev
    │   ├── PipFile
    │   └── PipFile.lock
    ├── jupyter
    │   ├── PipFile
    │   └── PipFile.lock
    └── test
        ├── PipFile
        └── PipFile.lock
```

and based on what environment you need to work on, you can use after you know where is your virtual env using `pipenv --venv` or to use a custom `venv` location https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/advanced/#custom-virtual-environment-location

Comment: My issue with this is that there is no sharing of dependencies. So the common "base" dependencies would have to be repeated in every Pipfile. I'm looking for a way to avoid the repetition.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This is what I did and my workaround when I decided to migrate one project to `pipenv`. I believe that it is possible to build a Makefile that generates different Pipfiles based on a shared requirements file. But I think this will add complexity in terms of project setup instead of using `virtualenv` itself. I'd like to see this officially supported by `pipenv`.

Comment: I adapted Pipenv in the hope of letting requirements directory trees and `requirements-<foo>.txt` files behind me forever. Now we get the same nightmare again. No, please, don't. Pipenv should have support for more than two groups. Speak out please at [GitHub #2303](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2303)

Comment: @DavidResnick Did you find any solution? We have quite similar problem i.e. we have multiple GitHub python repositories and each one has its own pipfile, so we find it difficult to manage many pipfiles so looking for better solution i.e. one pipfile for all the respositories or inheriting base dependencies. So far no luck. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: @SparkScalaDeveloper I'm sorry to say that I have not. I would love to switch to a tool that could manage this with my requirements instead of having to manage a mess of requirements files.